# htaccess 443 port added to url when using https RewriteRule & url 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

.htaccess file is performing a global 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS and the following code works fine

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

However I also have 30 or so Redirect 301 commands positioned below the above code and whenever they execute the resulting url has :443 incorrectly appended to the domain url and this causes issues with my current Wordpress installation.

Example :

```
Redirect 301 /oldDirectory/oldPage/ /newDirectory/newPage/
```

Incorrectly returns as :

```
http://www.domain.com:443/newDirectory/newPage/
```

Instead of :

```
https://www.domain.com/newDirectory/newPage/
```

Any suggestions or tips?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Found the issue, well actually it is not an issue.  It seems the :443 error only occurs when logged into the website Wordpress admin when loading a website page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} :443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ htt[b]ps:[/b]//www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Found the underlying issue. commented on original question. Thanks.